# PDL in abinitio

Tags: unix, ab-initio

There is command like this on the graph's parameter. I could not figure it out. It prints nothing.In abinitio help page, I could not find what -f means as well, thats why I am here.Could you please help me to understand it

```
$([ -f $FILE_PATH/$SUBJECT_AREA_X/`echo "$FILE_PATTERN_X" | awk -v RUNDATE=$RUN_DATE -F'_' '{for(i=1; i<=NF-1;i++) { printf "%s%s",$i, FS} { printf "%s%s\n", RUNDATE, substr($NF,length(RUNDATE)+1,length($NF)) }}'` ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([ -f ... ])`: This is a conditional expression that checks if a file exists. The -f flag is used to test whether the given path corresponds to a regular file.

`$FILE_PATH/$SUBJECT_AREA_X/...:` This part of the command is constructing the path to the file. It seems to involve variables like `$FILE_PATH` and `$SUBJECT_AREA_X` to define the directory structure.

`echo "$FILE_PATTERN_X" | awk -v RUNDATE=$RUN_DATE -F'_' '...awk command...'`: This part uses the awk command to process the contents of $FILE_PATTERN_X. It splits the input on underscores (-F'_'), and then it reconstructs the filename by appending the $RUN_DATE variable to the second-to-last field (excluding the last field, assumed to be a date-related part).

The entire awk command is encapsulated in backticks (``), which means the output of this awk command is substituted into the overall command.

The resulting constructed file path and name are used as an argument to the `-f` test in the `[ ]` conditional expression.

Comment: Thank you  a lot Dean. If we expect that there should be 100 files, in this case this means it checks if all  of them exist or not. Does it ?

Comment: @charmander you're 100% correct, it checks each file if it exists or not.

Comment: This isn't PDL -- it is a standard shell evaluation.  There are better ways of doing this.

Comment: @gbronner then add an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

That is a shell-interpreted parameter.  Best to write actual PDL.  Hard to exactly figure out what file it is looking for, but you can use parameters to build up the base, and then use string_split, string_join, and file_exists in PDL  to test if the file exists.